# How to convert emgu CV Mat type to something that can be used as ImageSource?

Tags: .net, wpf, emgucv

I am using emgu CV for computer vision tasks and need to manipulate the images on the fly and display the results. I couldn't find a way to convert Mat type to something compatible with ImageSource so that I can display it on the WPF Image control. The examples are all for 2.x and I am using 3.1. A lot of things don't work for 3.x. I searched for a few hours but couldn't find an effective solution. Is there a simple solution to that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        if (_capture != null && _capture.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Mat _frame = new Mat();
            _capture.Retrieve(_frame, 0);

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                image_control.Source = ConvertBitmap(_frame.Bitmap);
            }));
        }
    }

    public BitmapImage ConvertBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();

        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

OK. I found a way. I post it here in case other people have the same problem. Basically, I convert it to bitmap using ToBitmap method and then use BitmapImage to read it from a MemoryStream (which is dumped using Bitmap.Save method).

Comment: You should post working code in answer to help everyone.